# Raspbian watchdog fails at boot

Tags: raspbian, watchdog, crash

I have a raspberry pi 2 with original power supply (5v 2a) from farnell with raspbian. Tried more than 4 sd cards (lexar class 10, kingston class 8, trasncendet class 10) connected to the router via ethernet cable.

This rpi it's on a remote location only as a controller for ubiquiti AP.

For some reason that I can't figure out, some times after 2 or 3 days, some others, after 1 week, rpi suddenly stop / crashes and don´t answer via ssh or even no ping at all. I have to manually unplug / plug the power cord. I can't understand that if crash and boot and crash again, if don't even boot...

This is quite frustating, cause I have to go this location (drive more than 20km) just to unplug / plug the power cord.

Steps that I made without sucess:
-install watchdog, but on daemon.log appears that it's not doing nothing at all cause miss `/dev/watchdog`

```
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: starting daemon (5.12):
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: int=1s realtime=yes sync=no soft=no mla=24 mem=0
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: ping: no machine to check
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: file: no file to check
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: pidfile: no server process to check
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: interface: no interface to check
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: test=none(0) repair=none(0) alive=/dev/watchdog heartbeat=none temp=none to=root no_act=no
Nov  1 23:27:15 raspberrypi watchdog[31974]: cannot open /dev/watchdog (errno = 2 = 'No such file or directory')
```

Cause I don't find out out it's happening, can anyone help me to read logs in order to find what's happening?

Comment: I've edited your title to make this question more specific.  Note we aren't a discussion forum (please have a closer look at [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour)).   You'll have to break this down into separate questions if you want an answer to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear about there being no `/dev/watchdog`.

You may have to manually load the driver.  Try:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2708_wdog
sudo modprobe bcm2835_wdt
```

And see if `/dev/watchdog` now exists.  If it doesn't, or there are errors, immediately check `tail -n 25 /var/log/syslog` and/or `journalctl -xn 25` to see if there is any explanation.

You can also double check the modules are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep _wd
```

To load the modules at boot, add them to `/etc/modules`, i.e.,

```
bcm2835_wdt
bcm2708_wdog
```

You may only need to be explicit about the last one, `bcm2708_wdog`.  If that fails, try `tail -n 500 /var/log/syslog | grep wdog` after booting.

Comment: When I do modprobe bcm2708_wdog, system creates /dev/watchdog, but after reboot, this file /dev/watchdog dissapears. But anyway, even with this watchdog enable, how can dig into the real problem that it's causing this?

Comment: Yes, that will not persist across reboots.  It is pretty odd the service does not do this itself.  I've added a bit at the end about how to load them/it automatically.  If by "real problem" you mean the crashing/going offline thing, that's a separate and more complex issue.

Comment: OK I add  bcm2708_wdog to etc/modules, and after reboot the file at /dev/watchdog remains. Thanks for that @goldilocks. But I still want to dig to what really makes all of this. Wich logs or what can I do to get this needle?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` should contain everything.  You'll notice that the first message from boot is from `rsyslogd` indicating `start`, then messages from the kernel recognizable by the timestamp format -- seconds since start to six decimal places. This makes a boot easy to find by searching for the string `0.000000`.  *Immediately before this stuff you'll find whatever messages were left before shutdown.*   Normally the last one should be rsyslogd `exiting`; if you pulled the plug that won't have happened, but there may be clues about why the system went offline or froze up.

Comment: I will dig... hope with this watchdog helps to prevent frozen state. Once I saw a program for noobs like me that we could upload our syslog and check errors...